# how to kill IIS Express?

Tags: iis-7.5

I'm trying to deactivate the MS IIS Express Server, which comes with Microsoft Visual Web Developer Express 2010. While all non-weird servers can be stopped by simply stopping the service or ending the process, Microsoft made it different.

I tried:

```
iisreset /stop
iisreset /kill
net stop w3svc
```

I also tried to remove the http port 80 binding of the default site in the iis configuration manager. It still blocks port 80, showing a 404 error. Even after uninstalling MS Visual Web Developer Express 2010 and all of its components, the server is still there and shows a 404 site.

How do I remove this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ah, the service "Microsoft Web Deploy" (MsDepSvc) was the cause :)

Answer (score 4):

IIS Express can be uninstalled from Programs and Features aka run >> appwiz.cpl.

Comment: I didn't want to fully uninstall it, I just wanted to stop it. But, even after uninstalling the IIS from Programs and Features, it still served a 404 page on localhost:80, the only thing that helped was to choose a system restore point before the installation of vwd express. Seems like something went wrong.